# Data being erased when browser is closed.

Tags: javascript

I have this game board that stores the results of a tournament, and I can't figure out why the data (the game results being entered in through drop-down menu) gets erased when the browser is closed. Is there a way for my results to persist as long as the server is running?

The results are being displayed like this in `main.js`:

```
$.post('/postScores', results, function(scores){
  var gameBoard = "";
      for(var j=0;j<scores.length;j++){
          gameBoard+= '<tr>';

          for(var k=0;k<5;k++){             
            gameBoard += '<td>'+scores[k][j]+'</td>';
          }
          gameBoard += '</tr>';
      }

      $("#grid").append(gameBoard);

  });
```

And my scores are being stored in `server.js`like this:

```
 app.post("/postScores", function(req , res){ 
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    var results = [
  [ "", "team1", "team2", "team3", "team4"],
  ["team1", "x", req.body.e, req.body.h, req.body.k],
  ["team2", req.body.b, "x", req.body.i, req.body.l],
  ["team3", req.body.c, req.body.f, "x", req.body.m],
  ["team4", req.body.d, req.body.g, req.body.j, "x" ]
  ];

   res.json(results);
   res.end();

});
```

Full program: https://jsfiddle.net/Amidi/egp1hst3/10/

Comment: where exactly are the `results` being stored on the server?  It looks like you just reflect them back to the client.

Comment: you can use an in memory db like [redis](http://redis.io/) if you only care about keeping the data while the server is up.

Comment: the server must send the updated results when sending the initial content

Comment: So the results array must exist outside of the app.post in order to store it on the server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when you use javascript to modify the currently viewed page, these changes are by nature temporary by design. The next time you load the same page, it will load the HTML structure from the browser again and present it in it's original state to you. This does make quite some sense, as you want the browser to render the page that the server sent to you and not something else.

if you want to do permanent changes to the UI, you will either need to store the state on the server and included the changes in the html response, or save state on the client (e.g. in cookies or localstorage) and then also apply the modifications from there once the page is loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Use `localStorage` like this.

```
var yourData = '';
localStorage.setItem('gameData',yourData);
```

to retrieve

```
var retrievedData = localStorage.getItem('gameData');
```

Keep in mind that you cannot store arrays in `localStorage`, so you will have to stringify before you save to `localStorage` and parse when you retrieve the data. Also keep in mind that you cannot store more than 5MB in `localStorage`, which shouldn't be a problem for you. If you want persistence beyond the browser's cache, you will have to use a database of some kind.

Comment: Would I want to do this on the server side or the client side?

Comment: `localStorage` is strictly a client-side thing.

Comment: If it is data of actual value, you would probably want to store that data on the server side (e.g. in cases if the user reinstalls uses your application from a different computer). In that case, your server's response html would need to reflect the new html structure

Comment: So in the case of my program, in main.js, var yourData = scores //the array of scores being passed in from server? Then when I retrieve it, I have to retrieve it after the for loop? then do something like $("grid").append(retrievedData)?

Comment: you could do that - or ou could just in your server side logic append the html contents that were changed to your grid.